# Synch Clocks Between Android Devices on Same WLAN

Tags: wifi, clock-synchronization

1) It seems like there is already a synchronized clock (part of 802.11 specification) called a "local TSF timer". Is there any way to access it?

Android's ScanResult includes a timestamp described as "Time Synchronization Function (tsf) timestamp in microseconds when this result was last seen." Can this timestamp help me to synchronize?

2) If not, is there any easy way to accurately synchronize clocks between 2 Android devices connected to same WLAN?

3) What about synchronizing between iOS and Android devices?

r

Comment: See: http://www.ecsl.cs.sunysb.edu/tr/rpe20.pdf

Comment: Thanks dfc. Interesting reading but requires modifying drivers which is not really an option for an Android application.